# Is it possible to place an android animation on top of the phonegap web view?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm new to phonegap / java.  Because CSS Animation/Javascript animation is slow in Android, I am trying to create a Phonegap plugin that will place a native android animation on 'top' of the webview Phonegap uses.

Example:  A clock background in the asset HTML, and a 'handRotation' plugin that will put an a native android animation of rotating hands on top of the webview.

If this is not clear let me know.  I will continue trying to see if this is possible, and post my findings here, but any assistance is appreciated!

***UPDATE

I figured it out.

So given you have gotten through the [Phonegap Plugin tutorial](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android#Introduction) and you're sitting at your class that extends Plugin, here is what I did:

```
public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            final SampleView hands = new SampleView(webView.getContext());
            webView.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    webView.addView(hands, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                            ));
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


    return new PluginResult(Status.OK,  webView.getId());
}
```

*The thread/runnable stuff is from the 2nd example in the [Android UI Thread Ref](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) (any edits to the webView must be ran by the UI Thread)

** The magic door was knowing about the webView variable in the Plugin class, which refers back to the Phonegap webview.  I found out about this only after peaking into the class.

***The SampleView is a view that contains a rotationAnimation.  Here is the code for reference:

```
    public static class SampleView extends View {
    private AnimateDrawable mDrawable;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        Drawable dr = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.handtrim);
        dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Log.v("test", "test");



        RotateAnimation an = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 13f, 133f);

        an.setDuration(2000);
        an.setRepeatCount(-1);



        an.setInterpolator(getContext(), android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
        an.initialize(10, 10, 10, 10);

        mDrawable = new AnimateDrawable(dr, an);
        an.startNow();
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int cx = w / 2;
        int cy = h / 2 - mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        canvas.translate(cx, cy);

        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your great example. BTW do you know how to correctly animate webpage itself, not just a picture on the top of the view? if you start any standard animation in the plugin itself you will only see it when go to some other external screen and return back to the original webview. i want to avoid slow CSS animations when open a new page. BTW: Have you tried Sencha Touch 2 pre-release, demo looks not bad for page animations ? They also have a native wrapper packager.

Comment: Animating web page "transitions" can be done using jQuery mobile or the Sencha Touch stuff.  They utilize CSS Animations.  The gotchya is that anything < Android 3.0 doesn't support hardware acceleration for it, therefore making it slow.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html